# Create a nested objects from for-comprehension in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, yield, for-comprehension

I have a case class being instantiated based on some DB operations:

```
case class FullFight(fight: FightsRow, firstBoxer: BoxersRow,
    secondBoxer: BoxersRow, bookiesOdds: Seq[BookiesOddsRow])

val tupledJoin = for {
    f <- Fights
    b1 <- Boxers if f.firstBoxerId === b1.id
    b2 <- Boxers if f.secondBoxerId === b2.id
} yield (f, b1, b2)

db.run(tupledJoin.result).map(_.map(FullFight.tupled))
```

The problem is that I would not like to specify any bookiesOdds in this query (they are filled in some other query). Instead I would like to create a tuple tupledJoin containing an empty sequence of Seq[BookiesOddsRow] to create my case class' object. Is there any way of mixing that in a for-comprehension loop? I suppose I need something like that:

```
val seq: Seq[BookiesOddsRow] = Nil

val tupledJoin = for {
    f <- Fights
    b1 <- Boxers if f.firstBoxerId === b1.id
    b2 <- Boxers if f.secondBoxerId === b2.id
} yield (f, b1, b2, seq)
```

Is this possible? How to implement it correctly?

Best Regards

Comment: Your last snippet seems to be doing exactly what you describer. What's the problem?

Comment: I got the error `not enough arguments for method map: (implicit shape: slick.lifted.Shape[_ <: slick.lifted.FlatShapeLevel, (models.Tables.Fights, models.Tables.Boxers, models.Tables.Boxers, Seq[models.Tables.BookiesOddsRow]), T, G])slick.lifted.Query[G,T,Seq]. Unspecified value parameter shape.`

Comment: I don't see anything to do with slick in your snippet. Your question must have to do with some specifics of slick, but you haven't posted nearly enough details to identify that problem. I can tell you that there is absolutely nothing wrong with the `for-comprehension` snippet you posted.

Comment: Strange thing is that when I use `yield (f, b1, b2, 5L)` with the last static value - it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can only use DB actions in the for comprehension.
You could try this (not tested):

```scala
val tupledJoin = for {
    f <- Fights
    b1 <- Boxers if f.firstBoxerId === b1.id
    b2 <- Boxers if f.secondBoxerId === b2.id
    bookiesOdds <- DBIOAction.successful(Seq())
} yield (f, b1, b2, bookiesOdds)
```

Comment: You are right! I needed to convert my Query to Action and then make any map changes with it.